# Delete database and drop tables SSIS

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, sql-delete, ssis-2008

I have a scheduled SSIS package where it loads the data overnight into the data warehouse. Before loading, it drops the entire database and drops all the tables. But now I had a situation where I don't want to drop one table and want to do an incremental load using merge SQL statement. Because it is dropping the entire database, I won't be able to do that in the current scenario. If I change drop database to delete database, I think, I should be able to do incremental load on the table I want. Are there any possible complications of doing that. Can you foresee any problems if I change drop database to delete database, will I be missing something. Any thoughts highly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are you dropping the entire database? That's totally an overdo. You should work with the tables and keep the database, exactly because of this kind of problems.

Comment: There is no such thing as "delete database".  There is only Drop Database.  This is not like tables where we have "delete table" (which deletes contents) and "drop table" (removes the table).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know with `delete database` you only delete the rows whereas with `drop database` you delete all tables incl. the rows. If your logic works, you could do a `delete database`, then drop all tables except the one you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Does delete database delete records from all tables?

Comment: I don't want to empty all tables  I want to retain the records in one table and want to do incremental load. Does that mean that I can't use delete database in this scenario

Comment: You cannot delete/drop the database since the table you require is inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

A drop/delete of the database will remove all of the contents of the database. If the requirement is to retain a single table, you'll need to retain the schema and database that holds it as well.

If I'm understanding correctly, you're dropping the target database. Is this a STAGE database for the data warehouse? If so, you'll also have a TARGET (the main tables of the warehouse) that are loaded from STAGE. If this is the case, you should be able to run a MERGE statement from the newly STAGED table to the TARGET table.